# Cordova and Facebook login - Using Passport on Server Side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I'm building an app with Cordova and I'd like to use Node/Express as my backend.

My question concerns authentication. I like Passport and I'd like to continue to use Passport, but I'm a bit confused as to how to register users using Facebook's Javascript SDK.

I get a success object back from the JavaScript SDK:

```
{
    status: "connected",
    authResponse: {
        session_key: true,
        accessToken: "<long string>",
        expiresIn: 5183979,
        sig: "...",
        secret: "...",
        userID: "634565435"
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of just posting their access token to an API endpoint, and having my server retrieve some user information using the Graph API.

Is this the appropriate way to approach this? Are there more dignified/foolproof ways of implementing Facebook login with Cordova and Node/Express?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing the Facebook login directly from your client if you want to have access to it on your server. Have the client auth to Facebook through a request to your app's server.

Comment: Do you have any examples of an app that implements this?

Comment: Heroku used to make a "baseplate" app as a template for authenticating with Facebook (Facebook used to offer to create a new app with it back when they had integrated Heroku, actually), but that was a long time ago (and it didn't use Passport). These days, I'd just say follow the passport-facebook documentation, then use the accessToken you get when authenticating to make Graph API calls on your server.